# Google Speech-To-Text with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-speech

I'm working on a simple speech to text web app, I already have working server-side nodejs code and simple react page, but I don't have any idea how to glue them together, I was trying to implement various different weird stuff and either the react app doesn't get any data in return either there is error 500.

I would like to implement stop() function for the recorder after getting the transcription from Google as it is set to be listening only short commands, but the only solution that I could implement was the setTimeout function which is not exactly what I wanted.

EDIT: I have solved the problem with stopping recorder after getting the command and it works pretty good, however, any improvements are welcome. The solution was quite easy, I just modified the threshold from null to 0.5, `thresholdEnd: 0.5`. Still not resolved the front end for this express app.

EDIT 2: Funny thing, I accidentally discover [this stuff](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#examples-recognition) and it is exactly what I wanted... So much effort just to find this amazing and super easy solution, especially if you follow this [medium article](https://medium.com/@amanda.k.hussey/a-basic-tutorial-on-how-to-incorporate-speech-recognition-with-react-6dff9763cea5).

Can anybody help me, please?

Server-side code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3002;

const cors = require('cors')

// Node-Record-lpcm16
const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

function speechFunction() {
    const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
    const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
    const languageCode = 'en-US';
    const command_and_search = 'command_and_search';
    const keywords = ['turn on', 'turn off', 'turn it on', 'turn it off'];

    const request = {
        config: {
            encoding: encoding,
            sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
            languageCode: languageCode,
            model: command_and_search,
            speech_contexts: keywords
        },
        singleUtterance: true,
        interimResults: false // If you want interim results, set this to true
    };


    // Creates a client
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

    // Create a recognize stream
    const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', data =>
        // process.stdout.write(
        console.log(    
        data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
            ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
            : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
        )
    );

    // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
    recorder
    .record({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0, //silence threshold
        recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
        silence: '5.0', //seconds of silence before ending
        endOnSilence: true,
        thresholdEnd: 0.5
    })
    .stream()
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);

    console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
    // [END micStreamRecognize]
}

app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/speech-to-text/',function(req, res){
    speechFunction(function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error retrieving transcription: ', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error 500');
            return;
        }
        res.send(result);
    })
});

// app.use('/api/speech-to-text/', function(req, res) {
//     res.speechFunction();
// });

// app.get('/speech', (req, res) => res.speechFunction);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}, at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  onListenClick() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/api/speech-to-text/')
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({text: response});
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.onListenClick.bind(this)}>Start</button>
        <div style={{fontSize: '40px'}}>{this.state.text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have an error `events.js:177
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn sox ENOENT`
Please help me.

Comment: Can you write more about your problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have installed sox 14.4.1.exe.
`recoder.record({
        sampleRate: 16000,
        channels: 1,
        compress: false,
        threshold: 0.5,
        thresholdStart: null,
        thresholdEnd: 0.5,
        silence: '1.0',
        recorder: 'rec',
        endOnSilence: false,
        audioType: 'wav'
})`
I have got an error
`Error: spawn rec ENOENT`

Answer (score 3):

Replace onListenClick() code with the following

```
async onListenClick(){
const response= await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/api/speech-to-text/')
console.log(response)
this.setState(text:response.data)
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to stop the google api by clicking on a button. But above code will bring data on the react

Answer (score -1):

Title of the Question is wrong and they are implementing that with Node.js rather than react.js. I have been search for that problem so long. However, I called Google Speech APIs directly from the browser.

```
    async function trnascribeToGoogle(audioBlob: Blob): Promise<string>{

  const content = await toBase64(audioBlob);
  const apiKey = getGoogleApiKey();

  if(!apiKey || !content) return;
     const body = {
        "audio": {
             content: content
             },
        "config": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "alternativeLanguageCodes": [ "da-DK", "en-GB", "de-AT", "de-DE" ],
               },
      }

   const response = await fetch(`https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${apiKey}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
               });

  const jsonResponse = await response.json()
  const transcribedText = jsonResponse.results[0]?.alternatives[0]?.transcript;

    if(transcribedText){
       return transcribedText;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

If you want to directly Google Speech-To-Text with with React you can  check this article [Google Speech to Text with React](https://medium.com/@ali.anwar33/google-speech-apis-cloud-text-to-speech-and-cloud-speech-to-text-apis-from-browser-react-js-0773c9edc9d1).